# Dtype function is not working correctly in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dtype

I am trying to get the datatype of the column of dataframe using dtype, but dtype giving me wrong value when I am adding an empty row in the dataframe.

```
when i am adding one empty row then dtype will give wrong value for int --->float,float-->int.
```

example1:(without blank row dtype function working fine)

```
  Video Title  Up Ratings  Down Ratings   Views User Name  Subscribers
0    Adelaide        1295       1158259   600.5       Bob        25000
1    Brisbane        5905       1857594  1146.4       Tom        30000
2      Darwin         112        120900  1714.7      Dave        15000
3      Hobart        1357        205556   619.5     Sally        15005
4      Sydney        2058       4336374  1214.8      Rick        20000
5   Melbourne        1566       3806092   646.9      Mary        31111
6       Perth        5386       1554769   869.4   Roberta        11000

In [21]: df.dtypes
Out[21]: 
Video Title      object
Up Ratings       int64
Down Ratings     int64
Views            float64
User Name        object
Subscribers      int64
dtype: object
```

example:(when I am getting a different dtype when I am adding an empty row in dataframe.)

```
  Video Title  Up Ratings  Down Ratings   Views User Name  Subscribers
0
1    Adelaide        1295       1158259   600.5       Bob        25000
2    Brisbane        5905       1857594  1146.4       Tom        30000
3      Darwin         112        120900  1714.7      Dave        15000
4
5      Hobart        1357        205556   619.5     Sally        15005
6      Sydney        2058       4336374  1214.8      Rick        20000
7   Melbourne        1566       3806092   646.9      Mary        31111
8       Perth        5386       1554769   869.4   Roberta        11000

In [21]: df.dtypes
Out[21]: 
Video Title      object
Up Ratings       float64
Down Ratings     float64
Views            int64
User Name        object
Subscribers      float64
dtype: object
```

can anyone suggest me how to correct the dtype function functionality without converting datatype of columns explicitly from code end.?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga examples are already provided i am not aware to how to create a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a problem with the dtype function itself.
I would suggest you find those empty rows,

```
text_empty = df['column name'].str.len() > -1
[df.loc[text_empty].index]
```

and then skip those rows by passing them into pandas.read_csv()

you can also drop nan values with dropna()

Comment: any other solution.

Comment: do you need those empty rows?

Comment: then just drop them. if my answer helped you then can you upvote my answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need the empty rows, you can drop those rows by:

```
df=df.dropna()
```